# Swift - is it inefficient to calculate an immutable within a closure?

Tags: swift, performance, closures, immutability

I like case 2 because it keeps the relevant code together in one place, but if I do it like that does the constant get re-calculated each time I evaluate the closure?

```
let numCols = 99

// case 1
let spacing = (width - margin.left - margin.right) / (numCols - 1)
let xCoord = { (Int: col) -> Float in margin.left + col * spacing }

// case 2
let xCoord = { (Int: col) -> Float in
    let spacing = (width - margin.left - margin.right) / (numCols - 1)
    return margin.left + col * spacing
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it is inefficient to calculate an immutable within a closure.

Here is why. Let's say you have a code like this:

```
let numCols = 99.0
let width = 800.0
let marginLeft = 15.0
let marginRight = 20.0

// case 1
let spacing: Double = (width - marginLeft - marginRight) / (numCols - 1)
let xCoord1 = { (col: Double) -> Double in
    return marginLeft + col * spacing
}

// case 2
let xCoord2 = { (col: Double) -> Double in
    let spacing: Double = (width - marginLeft - marginRight) / (numCols - 1)
    return marginLeft + col * spacing
}
```

Those are case 1 and case 2 from your example, a bit modified to compile in Playground.

Let's make a simple for loop to measure execution of those functions 2500 times each:

```
let startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
for var i in 0...2500
{
    xCoord1(10)
}
let totalTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime
print("time: - \(totalTime) sec")
```

Case 1 executes in 0.99 seconds on my machine (can be a bit different if you have lower or higher hardware characteristics).

Now, let's see what we got if we do the same for case 2:

```
let startTime2 = CACurrentMediaTime()
for var i in 0...2500
{
    xCoord2(10)
}
let totalTime2 = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime2
print("time: - \(totalTime2) sec")
```

Case 2 executes in 1.49 seconds on my machine, which means that it is less efficient than case 1.

So, in case you have constant width, margin and number of columns it is always better to calculate the spacing once and store it in a constant.
However, if you don't have to repeat this calculation multiple times and just need it once, you can still keep it in the closure for readability.
Play with the measuring performance code in your context and see whether you lose performance or not, and make decision based on that.